# modify attribute with getattr - is it possible?

Tags: python, attributes, getattr

Let's say I have a class with three attributes :

```py
class Human:
    name = 'Thomas'
    age = 15
    robot = False
```

I know I can access the attributes with the .attribute :

```py
h = Human()
h.name # Thomas
h.age # 15
h.robot # False
```

However for some purposes I would like to modiy an attribute in a generic way :

```py
def modify_attribute(object, attribute, new_value):
    object.attribute = new_value
```

But python won't understand if I give `modify_attribute(h, name, 'Juliette')` or `modify_attribute(h, 'name', 'Juliette')`. In the latter case it compiles but it just doesn't change the name.

I read about `getattr()`and thought I could get away with `getattr(h, 'name') = 'Juliette'` however it appears this is not a valid expression. (I tried this because `help(getattr)` says `getattr(x, 'y')` is equivalent to `x.y`)

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Objects have a method named `__setattr__`.

Comment: If you want to *set*, not *get* the attribute, use `setattr()`: `setattr(object, attribute, new_value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can achieve this by using setattr.
i would give a sample code

```
>> class Person: ...
>> setattr(Person, 'age', 10)
>> print(Person.age)
10
```

**However**, it would violates principles in OOP
as you would have to know too much details about the object to make sure that you won't break the internal behavior of the object after setting the new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your specific question: no, you can't use `getattr` to *replace* an attribute (which is what your example is trying to do).  You *can* use it to get an attribute that, if mutable, can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter) & [@Richard Neumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515670/richard-neumann) who solved it in the comments section.

> If you want to set, not get the attribute, use `setattr()`: `setattr(object, attribute, new_value)`